# an alternative more efficient function to call data in PHP for sqlsrv_query sqlsrv_get_field needed

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

**Using PHP to display MSSQL data.**

I have a 32 fields of data stored in an MSSQL database. I need to retrieve and display this information online in specific order that does not match the field order.
 I currently have a solution but it is not the most efficient way of doing it. So i welcome assistance and advise on achieving a more efficient method.

Currently i create a function to call a single field of data for each field (thats 32 separate functions), then place each function inside a div in its correct order.

Here is my php function:

```
function field1() {

$serverName = "#"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"#", "UID"=>"#", "PWD"=>"#");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
// start of query function
$sql = "select field1 from [stats]";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

if(sqlsrv_fetch($query) ===false)
    echo "couldn't fetch data"; 

$result = sqlsrv_get_field( $query, 0);
echo "$result";
}
```

i am new to php so be kind on my lack of experience & knowledge :).

Comment: I think what you are looking for here is [sqlsrv_fetch_array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-fetch-array) with SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i am looking for :)